# Add/Delete Button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on this project, and what it is supposed to do is show a series of "business cards" that contain the name of someone and their image.  When you hover over the card an x button appears and clicking it will delete the card from the page.  There are also to inputs one for the url of an image and another for the name of the person, under these 2 inputs are a submit button, and when it's submitted it's supposed to create the card.

Right now I have the code to create the card, but it does not appear to be working.

```
    document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
        var addPhoto = document.getElementById('imagename').value,
        src = addPhoto +'.png',
        img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = src;

        var addName =document.getElementById('actorname').value;


    var card = document.createElement('div');
 card.setAttribute('class','card');

 var title = document.createElement('h1');
 container.innerHTML = addName;

var cardImage = document.createElement('div');
cardImage.setAttribute('class','card-image');

 var img = document.createElement('img');
image.setAttribute('src',addPhoto);

var button = document.createElement('input');
button.setAttribute('class','buttons');
button.setAttribute('type','image');
button.setAttribute('src','img/close.png');

card.appendChild(title);
card.appendChild(cardImage);
cardImage.appendChild(image);
cardImage.appendChild(button);
document.getElementById("lefty").appendChild(card);
};
```

Comment: Im having trouble understanding what your actual issue / question is. What is the current issue you're having?

Comment: How do I take 2 two inputs one for photo url, and one for name, and insert them into the card format I have ? Also, how can I delete the card, and it's contents with the X button I've set up.

Comment: Hi Jack, also having difficulty understanding your question. Also, I am confused by this line `"" + val +'.png'`, I don't see why the empty string needs to be there at the start. You can delete any element with the `removeChild()` function. Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Please make this into a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: The function that you're seeing adds the image, but what I need to do is add the image and the name text.  

There are 2 input lines prompts, whatever. You put a name and url into them, and THEN a card is supposed to appear with the image.  I have the card design, but no way to take the inputs and put them into a card.

Comment: a jsfiddle wouldn't help the situation.  Right now I have 2 input lines that create a large image, and no text, and some CSS and HTML that setup the cards that were in place initially.  

Put it this way their are 9 different cards with a photo and name each.  They appear on load. If I hover over them an X appears.  That x is supposed to delete the card. The 2 inputs take the name and photo of a person and create a new card which can also be deleted when hovered upon with the x button.

Answer (score 1):

To add a new card, you should set everything up from the ground. You should create the following in Javascript before adding it to the page:

```
<div class="card">
    <h1>the_name</h1>
    <div class="card-image">
        <img src="the_link"/>
        <input class="buttons" type="image" src = "img/close.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

You already know how to get *'the_name'* and *'the_link'* (the variables for your cards). I'm gonna use those variables in my solution. First you have to create all the elements.

```
var card = document.createElement('div');
card.setAttribute('class','card');

var title = document.createElement('h1');
container.innerHTML = the_name;

var cardImage = document.createElement('div');
cardImage.setAttribute('class','card-image');

var image = document.createElement('img');
image.setAttribute('src',the_link);

var button = document.createElement('input');
button.setAttribute('class','buttons');
button.setAttribute('type','image');
button.setAttribute('src','img/close.png');
```

Now you want to paste all the elements to the webpage. First append the elements to each other, then append them to the place you want to get them to (in your case the body).

```
card.appendChild(title);
card.appendChild(cardImage);
cardImage.appendChild(image);
cardImage.appendChild(button);

document.body.appendChild(card);
```

Comment: How do I take 2 two inputs one for photo url, and one for name, and insert them into the card format I have ? Also, how can I delete the card, and it's contents with the X button I've set up.

Comment: The first block of code looks like html.  Should I put that into the .js page, or the html page?

Comment: The first part is what your JavaScript will output. Do not place it in your html ;). Everything below the first html block is the javascript that will create your card.

Comment: One small issue with this code is that it won't insert your new cards inside the left-column. To fix this, add an ID to the left-column and change the last line of Nicky's code to `document.getElementById("left-column").appendChild(card);`

Comment: I had to stop for the day, but let me confirm I take the second code block, and put it into my .js file switching out the_name and the_link with the variables for those elements? I then take the third code block, and paste it into the body of the webpage?

Comment: I'm getting errors that the variables do not exist.  I did not set the inputs up as variables, but rather with an ID like this
<input name="name" type="text" required id="actorname" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Photo URL</label>
         <input name="photo" type="text" id="imagename" value="" />
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="Create" />

Comment: I added the second block of code to my .js and then the third block within <script> tags on my index page.  Is that right?

Comment: I just added this to the .JS, and it's still not working...

var addName = document.getElementById('actorname');
var addPhoto = document.getElementById('imagename');

Comment: @JackParker I advise you to start learning the basics of javascript. go to http://www.w3schools.com.

Comment: I did use Javascript in my last job, just not extensively, and learned the basics while at school.  It's just a matter of not using enough to keep it in my memory. So I'm doing little projects to get that back, and cannot seem to finish this one.

I was able to get the image with the code block in my initial code, but that was with a script tagged block on the html page. Now that I'm trying to set it up differently, nothing happens when I click create.

Comment: It's very unclear what the problem is, at this point. If you need more help I would recommend updating your question with your current code and the errors you're getting.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, I'm just not getting anything at all from the input.  I'll update the code now.

Comment: I edited my initial query, it's now on the bottom portion of the question.

Comment: You should put the JS code that Nicky gave you inside your `document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() { ... }` event. Or put it inside a function and add that function to an onclick event in the button's HTML tag.

Comment: So I should delete what I have in between the brackets presently, and add Nicky's code? Further, should I do what I was doing in an earlier version and add this to the top of the code in the brackets to retrieve the variables

var addName = document.getElementById('actorname'); var addPhoto = document.getElementById('imagename');

Comment: I just added what I have now to the initial query.  The button doesn't do anything when I click it with the above code.

Comment: Wow, a down vote for working on a project to better my skills. I graduated college in 2009, this is not homework. I have taken your advice, some of it has worked, some of it has not.  I am not a person who likes to leave things incomplete, and here I am with one element left to go, and I can't figure this out.  

You've seen what I've tried, and it should theoretically be functioning at this point, but it's not.  If someone could just point me in the right direction, I have done everything, and done things on my own, and I'm still coming up short.

Answer (score 0):

You have the basic idea, you just need to take it a few steps farther. For the delete you'll want to add an ID to each card and then call a JS function with that ID:

```
<div class="card" id="william">
    <h1>William Finley (Phantom of the Paradise)</h1>
    <div class="card-image">
      <img src="img/avatars/william.png"/>
      <input class="buttons" type="image" src = "img/close.png" onclick="removeCard('william')"/>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var removeCard = function(cardId) {
    var cardElement = document.getElementById(cardId);
    cardElement.parentNode.removeChild(cardElement);
  } 
</script>
```

When you create a card (which Nicky explained well) make sure you add the ID and onclick event to your element generation.

Comment: Thanks for the props, and you're right. That way everything is implemented nicely ;)

Comment: I just tried this and couldn't get it to work.  Do I put "william" where it specifies cardId or do I love the code alone, and put it together as is.

Comment: I noticed I put "card" where it should've been "cardId". Try it now.

Comment: Would you say the lack of an onclick element in the button itself could be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete an element in an odd way using javascript. First you have to get the domNode of the element you want to get rid of. For example one of the two nodes:

```
var unwanted = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
var unwanted = document.getElementById('id_of_unwanted_item');
```

then you have to execute the following function:

```
unwanted.parentNode.removeChild(unwanted)
```